# Kendo Grid Update Button Call Create Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

when i click update button if i didn't add any new column, work correct but after i add new column, update button sometimes call update function, sometimes call create function. thats my problem

**view**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("dersler")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Tanim).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Aciklama).Width(100);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                            .Window(conf => conf.Title("Yeni Ders"))
                            .TemplateName("DersTemplate"))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Create(create => create.Action("DersOlustur", "Tanim"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("DersGuncelle", "Tanim"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DersSil", "Tanim"))
    )
)
```

**controller**

```
#region Ders

        public ActionResult Dersler()
        {
            return View(Helper.Islemci.DersleriVer());
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public void DersOlustur([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Ders model)
        {
            if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               Helper.Islemci.DersTanimla(model);
            }

        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult DersGuncelle([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Ders ders)
        {
            if (ders != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var target = Helper.Islemci.DersAra(ders.Id);
                if (target != null)
                {
                    target.Tanim = ders.Tanim;
                    target.Aciklama = ders.Aciklama;
                    ders = Helper.Islemci.DersGuncelle(target);
                }
            }

            return Json(new[] { ders }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult DersSil([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Ders ders)
        {
            if (ders != null)
            {
                Helper.Islemci.DersSil(ders);
            }

            return Json(new[] { ders }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        #endregion
```

**and my helper ***

```
#region Ders
        public List<Kurslar.Models.Ders> DersleriVer()
        {

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM KURS.DERSLER";

            var dersler = DataManager.ReadIntoList<Kurslar.Models.Ders>(sql, _dbnumber);

            return dersler;
        }
        public Kurslar.Models.Ders DersAra(int ID)
        {

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM KURS.DERSLER WHERE ID={0}";
            sql = string.Format(sql, ID);

            var ders = DataManager.ReadIntoList<Kurslar.Models.Ders>(sql, _dbnumber);

            return ders.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        public Ders DersGuncelle(Ders model)
        {
            model.DurumKodu = "A";
            model.IslemNo = model.IslemNo + 1;

            IDatabase db = DataManager.GetDatabase(_dbnumber);
            using (DbConnection conn = db.CreateConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    model.Update(trans);
                    trans.Commit();
                }
            }
            return model;
        }

        public void DersTanimla(Ders ders )
        {
            ders.DurumKodu= "A";
            ders.IslemNo= 1;

            IDatabase db = DataManager.GetDatabase(_dbnumber);
            using (DbConnection conn = db.CreateConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    ders.Id = (short)db.GetNextIdFor(ders.GetType(), trans);
                    ders.Insert(trans);
                    trans.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
        public Ders DersSil(Ders ders)
        {

            IDatabase db = DataManager.GetDatabase(_dbnumber);
            using (DbConnection conn = db.CreateConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    ders.Delete(trans);
                    trans.Commit();
                }
            }
            return ders;
        }
        #endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ders oluştur function must be like that i had forgat refresh the grid after insert**

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult DersOlustur([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Ders model)
    {
        if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           Helper.Islemci.DersTanimla(model);
        }
        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your columns and it will work:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Id); // ID is the ID of the view model of course; i.e.,  your ID (primary key col.)
```

What is happening is that when you click the update, it doesn't know which ID it is supposed to take for the update and it is - as a result taking the entire view model into the update action method, which is of course all of your rows..

You don't have to show the id column, but it needs to be there.

So the above can be made into this:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Visible(false);
```

This worked for me.